# Can't execute a corutine using a suspend function in my main function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I'm trying to learn Kotlin coroutines and I have some code I don't understand or perhaps I need to dig deeper into it and experiment. But I'm having problem with a piece of code that won't execute when using `launch` in a coroutine scope using `runBlocking`.

I've created a simple get method for doing a GET request:

```kotlin
suspend fun get(url: String): HttpResponse? {
    try {
        return client.get(url) {
            headers {
                append(HttpHeaders.Accept, "application/json")
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        log.error("Error: $e")
    }

    return null
}
```

Then in my Main.kt I tried calling it using this code:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {

    println("Kotlin Start")

    val job = launch {
        delay(2000L)
        val response = get("https://some-domain.com")

        response?.let {
            println("Response: ${it.status}")
        }
    }
    job.cancel()

    println("Kotlin End")
}
```

That only gives me the output:

```
Kotlin Start
Kotlin End
```

So I tried just for fun doing this instead:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {

    println("Kotlin Start")

    get("https://some-domain.com")?.let {
        println("Response: ${it.status}")
    }

    println("Kotlin End")
}
```

And this time it gives me:

```
Kotlin Start
Response: 200 OK
Kotlin End
```

Which is what I want. Is this a valid use case to use the `launch` keyword or should I do this last example? And should I use `runBlocking`? A bit confused to be honest so some clarification would be helpful.

Comment: `launch` creates a "fire and forget" coroutine that runs asynchronously. It means that in the first code, you execute `launch` and then you cancel the job quickly after, before `delay(2000)` had a chance to return. If you need to wait for the result, your second example is the way to go. You could also look into using `async`, which returns a `Deferred` you can `.await()`, but I see no point for your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a valid use case to use the launch keyword or should I do this last example?

Well, one does what you want and the other doesn't. So I'd say "no", it's not a valid use case (since it doesn't do what you want) and "yes", you should do the last example (since it does what you want).

> And should I use runBlocking?

Yes, if it makes sense. No, if not.

[runBlocking](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html) is designed to be a bridge between "regular" code and coroutines, so you can run coroutines in otherwise synchronous code. Do you need this behavior?

> A bit confused to be honest so some clarification would be helpful.

You need to ask a more specific question about what you're confused about and need clarification on. If you're generally confused about coroutines, then your best bet is to spend time on the documentation and the infinite amount of content on the web explaining the topic.

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to answer if you should use `launch()` or not, because that depends on what do you need. `launch()` is used when you need to perform multiple operations concurrently. For example, if you need to execute two requests and you put them one after another without `launch()` then the second will start executing only after the first has finished. If you put each in a separate `launch()` block, they will both run at the same time, concurrently.

In your first example you cancelled the job immediately after launching it, so most probably it didn't even had a chance to start executing. To be honest, I'm not sure why you expected a different behavior. If we cancelled something, then it would be rather surprising to see it is still running.